# Vue 3 customize axios get,put,post

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vue-component

I want to customize my get,post,put functions with axios.
After doing the axios.create() operation, when I do the get operation, I want it to perform the then and catch operation there every time.

```
import axios from "axios";

export default (apiName = "") => {
    let headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    };

    let token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token") || "{}");

    if (token && token !== "") {
        headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token.AccessToken}`;
    }
    const instance = axios.create({
        baseURL:
            apiName === ""
                ? process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL
                : process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL + apiName,
        withCredentials: false,
        headers: headers
    });
    return instance;
};
```

```
axios.post('/api/Export/CopyShippingPlan/', plan)
            .then(handleResponse)
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
```

I want to define axios.post here after axios.create and have then and catch action wherever I call axios.post action. So I don't want to have to use then and catch where I use axios every time.

Comment: what issue is caused by handling the response and error where it is?

Comment: If you want to avoid duplicate code you can use a named function for the error handling as well. Maybe [Axios defaults](https://axios-http.com/docs/config_defaults) can have a default function for that? Not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're looking for `interceptors`:

- response interceptor will be called on every axios response
- request interceptor will be called before every axios request

Example:

```
const ApiService = axios.create()

ApiService.interceptors.response.use(
    config => {
        //your code

        return config
    },
    error => {
        console.log(error)
        return Promise.reject(error)
    })


ApiService.interceptors.request.use(
    config => {
        //your code
        
        return config
    },
    error => {
        console.log(error)
        return Promise.reject(error)
    })
```

After setting them up you don't need to do anything special just call `axios.get`, `axios.post`, etc.